# when setting WA_DeleteOnClose attribute on PYQT6 MDI subwindow , there is a no attribute error

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt6

```
subwindow = QMdiSubWindow()
self.subwin = CollectInfo()
subwindow.setWidget(self.subwin)
subwindow.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwindow)
subwindow.showMaximized()
```

there is the exception:

> > > 

Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8617.48)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\NetAuto\main.py", line 60, in add_subwindow
subwindow.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'WA_DeleteOnClose'
python-BaseException

Comment: `Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose`

Comment: subwindow.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose) , it works well, thank you for your answer sincerely